# Как определить нужный контроллер по URL в Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Могу ли я найти нужный контроллер по урлу или другими способами?

Comment: Если имеете ввиду в коде - найти в роутах можно, а если просто по урлу определить контроллер то нереально

Comment: @InDevX, `php artisan route:list`.

Comment: @RomanGrinyov если есть доступ к консоли значит он есть и к файлам...

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Можно выполнить консольную команду:

```sh
php artisan route:list
```

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                           | Name        | Action                                              | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                             |             | Closure                                             | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | _dusk/login/{userId}/{guard?} | dusk.login  | Laravel\Dusk\Http\Controllers\UserController@login  | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | _dusk/logout/{guard?}         | dusk.logout | Laravel\Dusk\Http\Controllers\UserController@logout | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | _dusk/user/{guard?}           | dusk.user   | Laravel\Dusk\Http\Controllers\UserController@user   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user                      |             | Closure                                             | api        |
|        |          |                               |             |                                                     | auth:api   |
+--------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

**2.** Можно посмотреть какой контроллер/экшен обрабатывает определённый URL в:

- `./routes/api.php`
- `./routes/web.php`